# Delayed image on second monitor, MacBook Pro 13 inch i5

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, display, vga-adapter, vga

I have a 2011 MacBook Pro conected to a LG Flatron L19WS monitor through a Mini DisplayPort to VGA adapter and the image is delayed from the MacBook Pro to the actual monitor. How can I fix this?

Comment: When you say delayed, you mean in terms of time, right?

Comment: no, I mean where is the image in relation to the monitor screen. English is not my native language, maybe I used the wrong word

Comment: If a picture would help illustrate this - please edit the question to add a URL - someone with enough reputation will embed it as long as it's relevant. Don't worry about your english - we all speak geek here as well :-)

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/aY75V.png

the delay is horizontal and a litle bit vertical like the red zone, making that I can't see the complete screen image in my monitor, btw I tried changing resolutions and monitor frequency but nothing. (and the first time I connected the monitor everything looked perfed). Because my reputation I cannot upload images to the questions

Answer (score 1):

The problem is because analogue (VGA) connection is used and the "auto" positioning does not detect the image bounds correctly. Check your monitor controls (menu) and move the image left/right and up/down (usually labeled HPOS/VPOS). Here are my recommendations:

- Use the native resolution (1440 x 900) and 60 Hz refresh rate.
- If still not centered, use the monitor's controls to position the image.
- If this does not work - try lowering the resolution or changing the refresh rate and again centering the image.

Answer (score 0):

If by "delay" you mean offset (delay relates specifically to time in English) then that is easily changed. You change the relationships between monitors by going to `System Preferences` and choosing `Displays`. Click on the `Arrangement` tab. That tab will allow you to change how  monitors are relatively positioned "virtually" by dragging them.